# Integral with bounds$ \pm \infty$

Tags: calculus, integration

Just a quick question that came across my mind today. In a "proper" integral, where the bounds are not $\pm \infty$, our definition or rather intuition behind the integral is to use an infinite number of rectangles to get an infinitely accurate solution. But when we extend the interval to $\pm \infty$, technically, we still use an infinite amount of rectangles, but our interval is infinitely large. How would using an infinite amount of rectangles be useful in this.

I understand the formula and how L'Hopital's rule can be used to evaluate the limit of the Riemann sum, just looking for an explanation for why it works (Perhaps a visual example?)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: "How would using an infinite amount of rectangles be useful in this": the same way that infinitely many infinitely thin rectangles can fill a finite interval, they can fill the whole axis.

Comment: "Some infinities are bigger than others" fits well here!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're talking about precisely but if you're looking for a concrete explanation of why it works, we can say it "just does". It's possible for an infinite series to converge (which is essentially what a Riemann integral is). A simple example I am sure you are familiar with would be

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n} = 2$$ Here we are adding infinitely many terms (you could also think of these terms as values for the area if you want), yet we converge at a finite value. [Look, an infinite addition of rectangles whose total area is finite.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9SCc.png)

Comment: I accidentally wrote this without being signed in, ha.

Answer (score 0):

Using definite integration, you can obtain integrals in finite intervals such as $\left[k-\frac12,k+\frac12\right]$. Then you sum the infinite *series*

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty I_k.$$